# Can you conform to WCAG 2.0 if you offer an alternative full service via a helpline?

Tags: accessibility, wcag2.0

WCAG 2.0 discusses [conforming alternate versions](http://www.w3.org/TR/UNDERSTANDING-WCAG20/conformance.html#conforming-alternate-versiondef) but seems to only mean web pages …

> **conforming alternate version**
>
> 1. version that conforms at the designated level, and
> 2. provides all of the same information and functionality in the same human language, and
> 3. is as up to date as the non-conforming content, and
> 4. for which at least one of the following is true:
>
>    - the conforming version can be reached from the non-conforming page via an accessibility-supported mechanism, or
>    - the non-conforming version can only be reached from the conforming version, or
>    - the non-conforming version can only be reached from a conforming page that also provides a mechanism to reach the conforming version

Would a full service via phone cover this alternate version criteria?

Answer (score 3):

No.

From [WCAG 2.0’s abstract](http://www.w3.org/TR/2008/REC-WCAG20-20081211/#abstract) (emphasis mine):

> Web Content Accessibility Guidelines (WCAG) 2.0 covers a wide range of recommendations for making **Web content** more accessible.

You can’t conform to WCAG 2.0 by having an accessible support hotline (or an accessible entrance to your office, or an accessible flyer, …), because WCAG’s scope is limited to *Web* content.

If the phone service would be part of your website (i.e., users can call the hotline from a widget on your page), then yes, it *could* be a conforming alternate version. However, keep in mind that not all users are able to speak and/or hear (either because of disabilities or because of missing hardware), so you would have to make your solution accessible for these users, too.

Answer (score 1):

You would not conform to the ***web*** accessibility guidelines, but you might fulfill the legal requirements in your country.

Answer (score 0):

Creating a separate service would not allow someone with a disability to use your website. The goal of the web accessibility guidelines is to allow everyone equal access to your site.